# Overwriting __getattr__ causing recursion

Tags: python, getattr

I'm trying to create a wrapper class and then overwrite `__getattr__` so that requests for attributes that are not in the wrapper class are passed through into the inner object. Below is a toy example where I used a list as the inner object -

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print 'HERE'
        return getattr(self.foo, name)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        try:
            return self._foo
        except:
            self._foo = [2, 1]
            return self._foo
```

I would like to do something like

```
 a = A()
 a.sort()  # initializes and sorts _foo 
 print a.foo
```

which prints `[1, 2]`

Finally, I need `_foo` to initialized when `foo` is called for the first time or when someone tries to get an attribute from `A()` that is not in `A`. Unfortunately, I'm getting in some sort of recursion and `HERE` is being printed many times. Is what I want possible?

Comment: Does `getattr(self.foo, name)` really make sense where `foo` will be a list according to the property? Which in turn means **"self.[2, 1]"** won't exist and so will try `__getattr__` again...

Comment: What is `a.sort()` supposed to do?

Comment: `getattr(object, name[, default])` https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: @L3viathan I've edited the question.

Comment: Now that you added that `a.sort()` should sort `a._foo`: is `_foo` literally the name and the only list attached to the object? In that case, you don't need all this getattrness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
return getattr(self.foo, name)
```

is actually:

```
foo = self.foo
return getattr(foo, name)
```

Now `self.foo` actually call this:

```
try:
   return self._foo
```

which, since your class defines `__getattr__` and - at least one the first call to `self.foo` - doesn't have a `_foo` attribute, calls `self.__getattr__("_foo")`, which calls `self.foo`, which etc etc etc...

Simple solution: make sure `self._foo` is defined before (ie in the initializer) instead of trying to define it in `foo()`.

You could also test for the existence of `_foo` in the instance's dict, but that will break inheritance if `_foo` is a computed attribute too - whether this is a problem or not depends on the context and concrete use case.

```
@property
def foo(self):
    if '_foo' not in self.__dict__:
        self._foo = [2, 1]
    return self._foo
```

NB: I assume you made `foo` a computed attribute to allow for lazy initialization of `_foo`, else it makes little sense. If that's the case, you can also, quite simply, creates `_foo` in the initializer with a sentinel value (usually `None`, unless `None` is a valid value for this attribute) and give it it's real value in `foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `_foo` to some sort of value initially, even if it's not the real one. Like this:

```
class A(object):
    _foo = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print 'HERE'
        return getattr(self.foo, name)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        if self._foo is None:
            self._foo = [2, 1]
        return self._foo
```

Comment: Defining `_foo` at the top-level makes it a class attribute, which will then be shadowed by the instance attribute created in `foo()`. While technically legal and seen in some code examples, this is considered a bad practice (it pollutes the class namespace for no good reason, makes the code harder to understand and can introduce subtle bugs). Instance attributes should be created in the initializer.

Comment: I don't know who considers this bad practice but feel free to edit